# Bootstrap form - label on right side of text box

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have tried almost everything but these fields are not getting horizontally aligned.

it should be like A: textbox  B

```
            <div class="form-group form-horizontal">
               <div class="col-sm-4">
                  <div class="form-group col-sm-10" style="border:1px solid red">
                        <label for="inlineFold" class="control-label col-sm-5">A :</label>
                          <div class="input-group  col-sm-4">
                             <input class="form-control" id="txtA" type="text" placeholder="" disabled>
                                <span>B</span>
                           </div>

                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-4">
                      <!-- more fields goes here -->
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-4">
                      <!-- more fields goes here -->
                </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

div is a block element,and therefore takes up all horizontal space.
just change it's property to inline.

**CSS**

```
.input-group{
    display: inline;
}
```

**OR**

use a span instead

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group form-horizontal">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group col-sm-10" style="border:1px solid red">
            <label for="inlineFold" class="control-label col-sm-5">A :</label>
            <span class="input-group  col-sm-4">
                <input class="form-control" id="txtA" type="text" placeholder="" disabled> <span>B</span>

            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap css the form-control style takes the total area width, use this solution it will works fine

```
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
              <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                  <label>A:</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" disabled="disabled" />
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                  <label>B</label>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
              <!-- more fields goes here -->
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
              <!-- more fields goes here -->
          </div>
      </div>
```

It support responsive also, which means you can see this view in any size of screen

hope this may helpful

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Drea and Jake. I had to remove input-group class on the div and create another with style display:inline and it worked for me. Actually i am using vertically aligned forms where i have to adjust few fields horizontally. Here is the adjusted code.

Now the next challenge is to control the spacing in between :)

```
<div class="form-group form-horizontal">
           <div class="col-sm-4">
              <div class="form-group col-sm-10" style="border:1px solid red">
                    <label for="txtA" class="control-label col-sm-5">A :</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-4">
                         <input class="form-control" id="txtA" type="text" placeholder="" disabled>
                       </div>
                      <div class="col-sm-3" style="display:inline">
                         <label>B</label>
                       </div>


              </div>
           </div>
           <div class="col-sm-4">
                  <!-- more fields goes here -->
           </div>
           <div class="col-sm-4">
                  <!-- more fields goes here -->
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you like small code. use pull-right and pull-left

```css
.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
}
#textbox {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="wrapper">
  <lable class="pull-left">Foo:</lable>
  <lable class="pull-right">Bar:</lable>
  <input type="text" id="textbox" class="form-control">
</div>
```